# PHP Regex Multiple Links Paragraph Display Domain Only

Tags: php, regex

The following code changes every link within a paragraph to be a clickable **[external link]** instead.

I have to run it twice to catch both HTTP and HTTPS.

**1)** Is there a way to turn this into a single line?

**2)** How would I also change it so instead of **[external link]** it display the domain name only? Like **google.com** but the actual link may be longer. The reason I use **[external link]** is to shorten the longer URLs.

```
//Regular HTTP links
$text = preg_replace('/(^|[^"])(((f|ht){1}tp:\/\/)[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&\/\/=]+)/i', '\\1<a href="\\2" target="_blank">[external link]</a>', $text);
//HTTPS links
$text = preg_replace('/(^|[^"])(((f|ht){1}tps:\/\/)[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&\/\/=]+)/i', '\\1<a href="\\2" target="_blank">[external link]</a>', $text);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a ? to make "s" optional.

https://regex101.com/r/loRV7S/1/

```
$text = preg_replace('/(^|[^"])(((f|ht){1}tps?:\/\/)[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&\/\/=]+)/i', '\\1<a href="\\2" target="_blank">[external link]</a>', $text);
```